# "Document exceeds allowed max BSON size. The max is 16777216." error using GridFS

Tags: ruby, mongodb, gridfs

I am trying to insert a 33 MB video file in my mongo database using GridFS and ruby and I have a systematic "Document exceeds allowed max BSON size. The max is 16777216.".
I thought the only way to insert file greater than 16 MB in a mongo collection was to use Gridfs so I suspect I do it wrong even though I copy/paste the Ruby driver example (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-driver-tutorial/#gridfs).

I am using Ruby 2.2.1, mongo driver 2.0.4 and a mongo db 3.0.1.
My code :

```
eDatabase = Mongo::Client.new(......)
@grid = @eDatabase.database.fs


myvideo = File.open("files/33mo.mov", 'rb')

grid_file = Mongo::Grid::File.new(myvideo.read, :filename => "myvideo.mov")
@grid.insert_one(grid_file)
```

And my logs :

```
21/05/2015 11:12:25] ERROR : Exception in main loop : Document exceeds allowed max BSON size. The max is 16777216.
[21/05/2015 11:12:25] ERROR : Backtrace : /Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/protocol/serializers.rb:157:in `serialize'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:153:in `block in serialize_fields'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:141:in `each'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:141:in `serialize_fields'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:70:in `serialize'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/server/connection.rb:123:in `block in write'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/server/connection.rb:122:in `each'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/server/connection.rb:122:in `write'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/server/connectable.rb:66:in `block in dispatch'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/loggable.rb:44:in `log'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/loggable.rb:65:in `log_debug'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/server/connectable.rb:65:in `dispatch'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/operation/executable.rb:35:in `block in execute'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool.rb:99:in `with_connection'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/server/context.rb:63:in `with_connection'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/operation/executable.rb:34:in `execute'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/operation/write/insert.rb:71:in `execute_write_command'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/operation/write/insert.rb:61:in `execute'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/collection.rb:196:in `insert_many'
/Users/Atome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/grid/fs.rb:78:in `insert_one'
server.rb:530:in `handle_addobject_message'
```

FYI, line server.rb:530 corresponds to

```
@grid.insert_one(grid_file)
```

Notes :

- the very same code is working fine with a < 16 MB file, i.e. both chance and file documents are inserted
- everything works fine when I use mongofiles command...
- other inserts in the db work fine from my application

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not a Ruby dev. GridFS can store files larger than 16MB, this is correct; however, the file is split up into chunks stored within `fs.chunks` (by default). The default chunk size is 255K. The metadata of the file (filename, file id, mode, etc.) is stored within `fs.files`. Together these two collections comprise the GridFS. I'm curious if it is creating multiple chunks within fs.chunks, or just a single large one (greater than 255K)?

Comment: @zammuts : thanks for your answer. Two comments : you say "Not a Ruby dev GridFS can store files larger than 16Meg" but that's exactly the advantage of GridFS, i.e. storing large files in mongodb. So, how is it possible to use GridFS within a ruby application (other than calling mongofiles from the code) ? Second comment, the chunk size is, by default, 255 K. So, if you have a 1 MB file, it will be splitted into 4 chunks with a common id. But, you still can change this chunk size to whatever size you want if you want smaller or larger ones.

Comment: that was two sentences: "I am not a Ruby developer" and "GridFS can store files larger than 16MB." - Second: that is correct, just make sure the chunk size isn't larger than 16MB.

Comment: OK but still, the chunck size I am using is 255 K and it does not work...when using the very same code with a < 16 MB file, it works fine : 255 KB chuncks are created. So, why doesn't it work with larger files ???

Comment: FYI, I have been in contact by phone with a mongodb representative. She asked me to post this question in the Mongodb google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mongodb-user/Document$20exceeds$20allowed$20max$20BSON$20size/mongodb-user/EbRYGlJGFhM/Xoy1eUGwLA0J) and an answer has been posted yesterday mentioning that : "Thanks for reporting this. I've opened a ticket in the ruby driver JIRA project if you'd like to track it:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-946

A fix is in code review and will be released with 2.0.5 soon"

Comment: @Thierry That should be an answer. Expand it a little and clean up the anecdotal tone, and then post it as an answer. Good Work!

Answer (score 2):

According to [mongodb jira ticket RUBY-946](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-946), this was a bug and should be corrected in the newly released Ruby driver 2.0.5. 
See comment in [this google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/Document$20exceeds$20allowed$20max$20BSON$20size/mongodb-user/EbRYGlJGFhM/fPq257wmM1IJ)